# How to increase display scaling above 200% in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, display, display-resolution, scaling

I have a laptop Dell Latitude E7470 with screen resolution `2560x1440`. I am currently using the display at `200%` scaling in display settings, however, I need a scaling factor above it like `225%` or `250%`. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

I have tried setting dpi with :

```
xrandr --dpi
```

and also setting scaling factor with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as such possible. However, you also can increase the font scaling factor. Setting it to e.g. 1.1 in combination with 200% scaling may already give a satisfying effect.

To set that, you may also use `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.1
```

or you can use Gnome Tweaks, Fonts tab. Gnome Tweaks is not installed by default in Ubuntu, so you may need to install it first.